# Get object for a few selected taxonomies

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, oop

I have some custom taxonomies that I would like to use as an object in a foreach loop.

I know these functions which returns the object for either all taxonomies:

```
global $wp_taxonomies;
```

or the post taxonomies object:

```
$taxonomy_objects = get_object_taxonomies( 'post', 'objects' );
```

but if I would like to only include a few taxonomies in the object like `video`, `audio`, `tv` and `radio` (all taxonomy names), how would I go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of a function to get only specific term objects for a post type but it is not hard to filter out the ones you want. For example:

```
$taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( 'post', 'objects' );
$taxonomies = array_intersect_key($taxonomies,array_flip(array('category','post_tag')));
var_dump($taxonomies);
```

But since you know the taxonomies you want, you could also just use `get_taxonomy( $taxonomy )` multiple times.

```
$tax_objects = array();
$taxlist = array(
  'category',
  'post_tag'
);
foreach ($taxlist as $tax) {
  $tax_objects[$tax] = get_taxonomy($tax);
}
var_dump($tax_objects);
```

Or you may be making this more complicated than it needs to be. You can just simply use the taxonomies you need:

```
$taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( 'post', 'objects' );
if (!empty($taxonomies['category'])) {
  var_dump($taxonomies['category']);
}
```

Obviously, all code above uses Core taxonomies (so I can test things) but you can easily swap those out for your own specialized taxonomies.

Comment: That's a great answer for the "average Joe". Simple but a very helpful tutorial. I have lost count of the number of times you helped me out here. Thanks a lot. I use this to filter out some metaboxes in the edit post admin page by means of the "Order bender" plugin and with `get_taxonomy()` , as you suggested, the plugin will no longer display all the metaboxes, only those I need.